# Can I use an existing (deployed) contract on ethereum mainnet instead of deploying myself? (NFT)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, nft

I'm trying to learn how to mint NFT's in an economic way. I have some experience with smart contracts but it's a while ago. I have looked for an answer to this question but could not find it.

I have deployed this contract on testnet: https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721 and created an NFT by interacting with the contract.

Deploying the contract is very expensive on main-net, much more so than interacting with it.

Now I was wondering: isn't there any deployed contract on mainnet already? That I can use to mint an NFT?

Comment: You might not be aware, but there is a dedicated Stack Exchange site for Ethereum at [ethereum.se].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.